# How to move section gizmo in Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

When using the section tools in the Forge viewer on models that cover a large area it's very difficult to use. Is there any way I can move the section gizmo to a certain point in the model? I would prefer it to be in the center of current view, not in the center of the bounding box of the entire model.

Comment: Is there any news on this one? On large models the section tools are more or less useless as it is centered in the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no official way to change the behavior of the section tool and its gizmo. I do agree that moving the gizmo relative to the view would make more sense than just using the bounding box, and I will report this request to the dev. team.

Comment: Btw. according to the dev team, viewer version 7.3 brings some section tool improvements - the initial placement of the gizmo now takes the viewport into account, and there are also context menu entries for initializing the section plane based on the selected geometry.